# Issue with displaying images in JavaScript(DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My task is to add 5 images (smile.png) to 5 randomly positions  in the left half of the page which is a div with id="leftSide" and size 500x500px
so here is my code

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var count = 0;

function generateFaces(){
  while(count < numberOfFaces) {
    var this_img=createElement("img");
    this_img.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    var toppos = Math.random() * 400;
    var top_pos = Math.floor(toppos); 
    var leftpos = Math.random() * 400;
    var left_pos = Math.floor(leftpos);
    this_img.style.left=left_pos + "px";
    this_img.style.top=top_pos + "px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(this_img);
    count+=1;
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position:absolute
}
div {
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
#rightSide { 
  left: 500px; 
  border-left: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<body onload="generateFaces()">
  <h1>Matching game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
  <div id="leftSide"></div>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>
```

It should do
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3vqQ.png)
But instead it shows just a white page.

Comment: Open your fiddle, hit F12 to open the Console, and see what the problem is for yourself.

Comment: *hints: jsFiddle wraps code in a onLoad handler, you have to set "nowrap in body" option. `createElement` doesn't exist*

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u66q7zp6/1/

Comment: @adeneo So that's what that option does, very good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change createElement to new Image();

```
var this_img=new Image();
```